# position:fixed in reveal.js

Tags: position, fixed, reveal.js

I am trying to make a header for my reveal.js presentation that sticks to the top of the screen. The content in the header is dynamic on a per-slide basis, so I have to place the markup within the section tag.

Apparently position:fixed does not really provide satisfying results in reveal.js if the markup is within the section tag. I can't really make out why that is exactly, but I found some info in the github repo suggesting setting the presentation size to fit the viewport size with:

```
Reveal.initialize {
    ...
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    ...
}
```

But it still doesn't work for me - it seems the presentation is not really affected by the above. Here is a demo:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/706446/_linked%20stuff/reveal.js/index.html

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: No ideas. But I want to do the opposite (place a block on the lower left) and I'm equally frustrated.

Comment: Here is the thread on github I was mentioning, but I was not even able to make the show fill the viewport: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/857 I have not still achieved this, but my plan is to put some text in the slide and then use javascript to move it out of the slide on load.

Answer (score 13):

Add this to css:

```
.reveal.slide .slides > section, .reveal.slide .slides > section > section {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}
section > h1, section > h2 {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}
.print-pdf .reveal.slide .slides > section, .print-pdf .reveal.slide .slides > section > section {
  min-height: 770px !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
```

- Demo https://rawgit.com/rofrol/reveal.js/fixed_header/
- Code https://github.com/rofrol/reveal.js/blob/fixed_header/index.html#L411
- Discussion https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/1312 https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/180

Answer (score 5):

At the end of your main.html add:

`Reveal.initialize({
center: false,
})`