# Section size in Reveal.js

Tags: css, reveal.js

I am trying to have all my headers, text etc. in the same position no matter how much content I have in a section.
My idea is to fix the `section` size to be the same as `slide` and then position my headers etc. percent-wise in the section.

I'm sure I'm missing an easy fix but I haven't understood how to make the section the same size as slide, setting `height: inherit;` or `height: 100%;` in reveal.css doesn't seem to work (section becomes too high), while specifiying the width in that way works.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think this might have to do with the way sections can be nested vertically...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [position:fixed in reveal.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241903/positionfixed-in-reveal-js)

Comment: My solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241903/positionfixed-in-reveal-js/34922750#34922750